# How to get a user's profile picture URL?

Tags: 8, users, uri

I need to get the user's profile picture using the following code:

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain(\Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())->user_picture->first()->view('large'))
```

It returns an object with the image tag, but it fails with the `_Call to a member function view() on a non-object_` error when a user has no profile picture set.

I also tried the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/167313) to "[How do I get the default user picture?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167196)", but it gives the error

> Drupal\Core\Database\InvalidQueryException: Query condition 'file_managed.uuid IN ()' cannot be empty.

Answer (score 6):

The code is OK, but you have to check if the field is not empty:

```
if ($user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())) {
  if (!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
    $picture = $user->user_picture->view('large')
  }
  else {
    $picture = // get default picture
  }
}
```

In Drupal 8 don't use render service. The new template system does this automatically.

Comment: Saviour, worked as expected! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
// Getting the actual user uid.
$uid = \Drupal::service('current_user')->id();
// Getting the actual user entity.
$user = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('user')->load($uid);
// Getting the user picture.
$user_picture = $user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri();

// To use dpm you need the devel module.
dpm($user_picture);
```

Comment: It's preferable to use this way to call a user entity. You'll need to use this approach, or else, it wont respect the Drupal coding standards that requires you to put the call  "\Drupal\user\Entity\User" on the top inside a "use". If you use the 4k4's answer, you'll have a problem if you need this in a static function. This answer here is the good one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the getAccount method on the AccountProxy class, which should save an entity load if the account object already exists.

```
$account = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount();
```

2. Use methods to on the field item (entity reference) to check if there is a value.

```
if (!$account->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
```

3. Instead of using the renderer to render the plain output from the field item. This data can be retrieved via some other methods.

```
   $image_url = $account
                  ->user_picture
                  ->first()
   // Fetch the file entity associated with the image item entity reference.
                  ->get('entity')
   // Use the url() to call file_create_url() as in Drupal 7 to get the URL.
                  ->url();
}
```

Comment: I got an error **Call to a member function isEmpty() on a non-object** on the second point. Also, on `print_r($account)`, I got a `Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession Object` with no user_picture property.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a PHP issue.  You shouldn't put calls to object methods within the arguments of another function, especially if you're dealing with fields on a drupal entity, as they may be set or not set.

```
$uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

// Might be zero if user is logged out.
if ($uid) {
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
   // check that the field exists and that it has a value.
  if (!empty($user->user_picture) && $user->user_picture->isEmpty() === FALSE) {
    $image = $user->user_picture->first();
    $rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($image);
  }
}
```

Also, Drupal coding standards suggest you try and keep your lines under 80 characters, and I feel that's good practice, as it makes the code more readable.  See:

https://www.drupal.org/node/935284

Also, here's a post about getting the default image for a user.  You might want to set a default image for this field.

[How get the default user picture?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167196/how-get-the-default-user-picture)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way on Drupal 8, create a custom module with Controller and send a variable to Twig:

```
$pictureUri = $user->user_picture->entity->getFileUri();
                         $style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');
                         $urlPicture = $style->buildUrl($pictureUri);
```