# Get paths of files attached to the node from field name

Tags: nodes, 8, entities

How can I get the paths (URLs) of files attached to the node from field name in Drupal 8?

I tried using Drupal 7's `node_load()`, but that does not return paths of the files:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$node = node_load($node->id());
var_dump($node);
```

Comment: This seems to be very similar to what you asking for: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/222948/42650

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it like this:

`$file_uri = $node->field_machine_name->entity->getFileUri();`

If your field allows for more than 1 value, then:

```
$file_uris = array();
foreach ($node->field_machine_name as $value) {
  if ($value->entity) {
    $file_uris[] = $value->entity->getFileUri();
  }
}
```